# Prove the set $\{\sin{x},\sin{2x}\}$ in $F(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ is linearly independant

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, independence

Prove the set $\{\sin(x),\sin(2x)\}$ in $F(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ is linearly independent

I know this has been asked before, but I'm looking for a solution without integration that makes sense.

Essentially we must show that if

$$r_1\sin(x)+r_2\sin(2x)=0,$$ then the **only** solution is $r_1=r_2 = 0$, where $r_1,r_2\in\mathbb{R}$.

This should hold for **all** $x$.

Can I get an answer that doesn't deal with integrating and such?

If we consider $x=0$, then the value of $r_1,r_2$ do not matter, as the equation still evaluates to $0$, but in this case $r_i\neq 0$, so does this mean its not linearly independent?

Comment: I don't know about "integration and such", but the quick approach is to compute the [Wronskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian), which involves "differentiating and such".

Comment: Note that if you rearrange your equation and use the fact that both functions are nontrivial, we obtain $\sin (x) = a \sin(2x)$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$. Thus it suffices to show that $\sin (x)$ is not a scalar multiple of $\sin (2x)$, which can be done (for example) by evaluating the functions at two points as demonstrated below.

Comment: What is the meaning of nontrivial in this context?

Comment: The dummy variable $x$ might be confusing you.  We say two functions $f,g$ are linearly dependent if there are nonzero constants $r,s$ such that $rf + sg$ is the zero function.  This is not a pointwise statement!  We are NOT saying "for every $x$, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are linearly dependent".  Indeed, for a particular value of $x$, $f(x), g(x)$ are not functions but numbers, and two numbers are always linearly dependent.

Comment: @KSplitX: "$f$ is nontrivial" means "$f$ is not the zero function", i.e. "there exists $x$ such that $f(x) \ne 0$".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $x=\pi/4$ and $x=\pi/2$ and solve the equations.

$x=\pi/2$ you obtain $r_1\sin(\pi/2)+r_2\sin(\pi)=r_1=0$,

$x=\pi/4$, $r_1 \sin(\pi/4)+r_2\sin(\pi/2)=r_2=0$.

Comment: $\pi_4$ is a creative typo.  Note also that `\sin` tends to look better than `sin`.

Comment: but shouldnt linear indepdendence hold for **all** x, how can we just "Set" x to be $\pi/4$?

Comment: if $r_1sin(x)+r_2sin(x)=0$  for all $x$ it is true in particular for $x=\pi/2$ and $x=\pi/4$.

Comment: @KSplitX the functions are linearly *dependent* if we can find $r_1$ and $r_2$ such that $r_1 \sin(x) + r_2 \sin(2x) = 0$ for all $x$.  The functions are linearly *independent* if they are not linearly dependent.  Now, carefully consider the logical negation of "there exist real numbers $r_1$ and $r_2$ such that for all $x$, $r_1 \sin(x) + r_2 \sin(2x) = 0$".

Comment: The point that confuses me is that suppose we set $x=0$, then we get $r_1\sin(0)+r_2\sin(0)=0$, but $r_1,r_2$ need not be $0$, they can be something like $5, 10$. So in this case we have shown that the equation can evaluate to $0$, even though the scalars are non-zero. So wouldnt this imply depdendece ?

Comment: @KSplitX: You have to show that if $r_1 \sin x + r_2 \sin (2x) = 0$ for all $x$ then the **only** solution is $r_1 = r_2 = 0$. The for all $x$ is important.

Comment: So then why did @TsemoAristide **specifically** choose $x=\pi/2$ if he had to show for **all** x?

Answer (score 2):

If $\sin x$ and $\sin 2x$ were linearly dependent, then there would exists real numbers $r_1$ and $r_2$ such that the equation 
$$r_1 \sin(x) + r_2 \sin(2x) = 0$$

would be true **for all $x$**

\begin{align}
   r_1 \sin(x) + r_2 \sin(2x) &= 0 \\
   r_1 \sin(x) + 2 r_2 \cos(x) \sin(x) &= 0 \\
   \sin(x) (r_1 + 2 r_2 \cos(x)) &= 0 \\
\hline\
   \sin(x) &= 0 \\
   \cos(x) &= -\dfrac{r_1}{2r_2}
\end{align}

The above equations imply that, for all $x$, either $\sin(x)=0$ or
$\cos(x) = -\dfrac{r_1}{2r_2}$. Since that is clearly false, then $\sin x$ and $\sin 2x$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Not quite, this shows that for all $x$ either ($\sin x = 0$) or ($\cos x = -r_1/2r_2$), not ($\sin x = 0$ for all $x$) or ($\cos x = -r_1/2r_2$ for all $x$). Of course, this is still a contradiction..

Comment: @Nitin - OK, $\forall x, P(x) \vee Q(x)$ is not the same as $(\forall x, P(x)) \vee (\forall x, Q(x)) $

Answer (score 1):

$$\quad{r_1\sin(x)+r_2\sin(2x)=0\\
r_1(\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i})+r_2(\frac{e^{2ix}-e^{-2ix}}{2i})=0\\
r_1(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})+r_2(e^{2ix}-e^{-2ix})=0\\\times e^{2ix}\implies\\
r_1e^{3ix}-r_1e^{ix}+r_2e^{4ix}-r_2=0 \\\forall x \in \mathbb{R} :r_1e^{3ix}-r_1e^{ix}+r_2e^{4ix}-r_2=0 \\\text{ for example } x\to -\infty\\\underbrace{r_1e^{3ix}-r_1e^{ix}+r_2e^{4ix}}_{\to 0 }-r_2=0 \implies r_2=0}$$ then apply $r_2=0 \implies r_1=0$

Comment: you use the $\to$ symbol for two different purposes (and language levels), that is confusing; Maybe it is more cleat to use `\implies` ($\implies$) for the implication and use $\to$ only for convergence.